# Why doesn't my DIV color the background?

Tags: css

I have the following code:

```
#wrapper {
    position:relative; top:0; right: 0; left:0; bottom: 0;
    display: block;
    background: #657575; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #657575 0%, #758585 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,#657575), color-stop(100%,#758585)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #657575 0%,#758585 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #657575 0%,#758585 100%); /* Opera11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #657575 0%,#758585 100%); /* IE10+ */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#657575', endColorstr='#758585',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */
    background: linear-gradient(left, #657575 0%,#758585 100%); /* W3C */
}
```

But when I publish I don't see anything. Am I setting something wrong?

I have my wrapper set up right at the start as in:

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
```

Comment: Does the div have content or is it empty?

Comment: The DIV has a lot of other DIVs as content: <body>
<div id="wrapper"><div id="hdr"><div id="hdr_top"></div><div id="hdr_sgn"><div id="hdr_msg1">xxx</div><div id="hdr_msg2">xxx<div id="hdr_msg3">xxx..</div>. </div>  etc. I'm using the DIV just to set the background. I tried setting the HTML and BODY background but always seem to have some small problem with scrolling and things.

Comment: Including your HTML within the posting might be helpful.

Comment: is everything floating within the `#wrapper`?  if so, i would first define a fixed width and height and see if you can get the background to show up.

Answer (score 0):

works fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/bvTMW/

Answer (score 0):

How about adding height & width